# E-mails arriving late when using google apps account as a sendmail relay

Tags: sendmail, g-suite

I'm using a google apps account as a sendmail relay for sending some e-mails. E-mails sent through the sendmail are consistently late, or not arriving at all. E-mails sent directly through the gmail web interface are arriving imediately.

When I send an e-mail to: check-auth@verifier.port25.com, I receive the following response:

> SPF check:          pass
>
> DomainKeys check:   neutral
>
> DKIM check:         neutral
>
> Sender-ID check:    pass
>
> SpamAssassin check: ham

Which seems fairly normal.

There are two strange entries on the sendmail log:

> field=cn_subject, status=failed to
>   extract CN
>
> and
>
> version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL,
>   bits=256/256

But, as far as I have gone, these errors shouldn't have this impact on my e-mail delivery.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the full headers from an email which was late?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sendmail setup: [mail hosted at Google, web server elsewhere](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2011/03/14/mail-hosted-at-google-web-server-elsewhere/)